# redirect_uri_mismatch Azure AD B2C with angular using MSAL

Tags: angular, azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

While using `loginRedirect()` or `acquireTokenRedirect()`, I am getting the following error:

> redirect_uri_mismatch:AADB2C90006%3a The redirect URI 'http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a4200%2fsubscription' provided in the request is not registered for the client id 'blah-blah-blah'.
> Correlation ID%3a 29978079-45a7-4f85-a9bf-4cde9d3adc84
> Timestamp%3a 2017-09-29 05%3a32%3a22Z

Note: The client ID is the same that I am using in my tenant config as well as what is configured in Azure.

Please let me know why I am getting a `redirect_uri_mismatch` error every time and what the code `redirect_uri_mismatch` `AADB2C90006` means. If you have a reference, please share a link.

Comment: What have you configured as the reply urls for the app?

Comment: what do you mean by reply URLs? are you talking about configurations?

Comment: Yes, the configuration for your app in Azure AD.

Comment: export const TENANT_CONFIG = {
    tenant: "xyz.onmicrosoft.com",
    clientID: 'blah-blah-blah',
    signInPolicy: "B2C_1_SignIn",
    signUpPolicy: "B2C_1_SignUp",
    b2cScopes: ["https://xyz.onmicrosoft.com/api/id_token"],
    redirect_uri : "http://localhost:4200/"
};

Comment: What have you configured in Azure AD B2C?

Comment: all the required information. and yes for redirect Uri I also set http://localhost:4200 in Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155585/discussion-between-chaitanya-chauhan-and-juunas).

Answer (score 8):

If you're confident you have added the redirect URI(s) to the app registration then you have to **WAIT**.  Waiting about 1-3hrs seems to resolve the issue.

During that window, it can be flaky as sometimes it works and sometimes it won't (`AADB2C90006`).  We must be hitting one endpoint w/ the old version sometimes and vice versa ‍♂️.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add http://localhost:4200/subscription as a reply URL in your B2C Web App configuration.  [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga#register-a-web-application) should help.

[image: b2c web app configuration]

Comment: If this thing I have to configure then for each and every URL of my app I have to configure the same. whenever I am calling loginRedirect() so before that I am routing user to root url, that time working fine. but when its redirecting and done login then that time its again going to the previous URL. so i guess this is issue of MSAL implementation.

Comment: @ChaitanyaChauhan - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47687296/185123), it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I was able to fix it by running my user flow directly by going to the user flow in the Azure portal, clicking "Run user Flow" which opens the B2C url in the browser, then in Chrome, I long pressed the refresh button with the dev tools open and selected "Empty Cache and Hard Reload". Then when I go back to my app, I don't get that redirect_uri_mismatch error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (with a Blazor application) and even I clear the cache of my browser, using InPrivate mode,... it did not work.

The only way to fix the issue for me was to just recreate the app registration with exactly the same settings (Redirect URI,...).

Of course, I just had to change the Client ID setting for MSAL library in my Blazor app, and it work ! So, I think it is related to an issue in Azure B2C side...