# Azure AD B2C: The redirect URI provided in the request is not registered for the client id... but it actually is

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have the following Azure AD B2C Application (which we will call `aadb2c`) with the following settings

```
  Include web app/ web API: YES
  Allow Implicit Flow: YES
  Reply Url:
   - https://localhost:44339/
   - https://productionURL.com
   - https://productionURL.com/

   App ID URI (which is optional): none
   Native CLient: NO
```

This Application is what our website `https://productionURL.com` uses to login it's users with azure AD B2C.

However, on production we keep on getting the error:

`The redirect URI 'productionURL.com' provided in the request is not registered for the client id 'aadb2c'`

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46489570/2155668) we should add the link to out reply url. 
But as you can see above, we already included `https://productionURL.com` in the "Reply URL" section
of the Azure AD B2C blade.

What could be causing this error to happen? How do we resolve the redirect URI request not registered error?

Comment: In my case (.Net6 Web App) it was missing slash at the and of the URI: was "https://localhost:44316/signin-oidc" has to be: "https://localhost:44316/signin-oidc/"

Comment: For me, the new change takes time (>1 hour) to be effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours looking at our code and finding no traces of the url without any protocol or any trace of "http:", we now had to look at our deployment orchestrator.

Apparently in Octopus we are deploying the app with an incorrect URI: it's missing the protocol "https://"

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be configured in the code as well and you need to make sure that the protocols match. This can also happen if there's a mismatch with the tenant ID or the app ID.

Check the B2C callback request in Chrome DevTools > Network with "Preserve log" to see what URL is being returned. This should give you insight into the problem.

As an extra measure to ensure that the protocols are matching, you can add:

```
if (context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Contains("http:"))
{                    
    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Replace("http:", "https:");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marilee. Looking at the code we found no traces of `http:\\` and url without any protocols.
We finally looked into the deployment and found that it was deployed with an incorrect endpoint. It's now working

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: If you have a chance you should consider posting that as the solution and marking it as answer so that others can find the resolution. :)

Comment: Turscak I wonder though.. could it be a possible (as an update) with azure AD B2C to just smartly identify if the return URL is missing the proper protocols and just supply it if incorrect? or just allow http:// or no protocol on the "Return URLs" page?

Answer (score 1):

I needed someone with elevated privileges to go in and add my apps redirect URL to be allowed in AD B2C.